# Event Handling for onChange with Argument

Tags: bind, reactjs

I am learning Reactjs and want to design a table of 5 rows where each row contains 5 `<input type="text">`.

On the onChange event of `<input>`, I want to alert the row and column number of it. So I want to pass 2 arguments to `onChange`, these are "row" and "column" number of it.

I am using this code but this does not work

```
React.createElement('input',
{value:newValue,onChange:_this.handleChange.bind(this,index,row)
```

In the event handler I am using this:

```
handleChange: function(event,index,row) {
    alert(" index"+index + "rows are" + row);
},
```

Comment: You can make a React-component for each table cell. Then each cell would know its row and column. You can then pass it as properties to each cell. That is the most "React"-way, but I am still uncertain of what you want to do with this information.

Comment: Please include a sufficient amount of code so that we can understand what problem you're having.

Comment: Also, when you use `bind` on the event handler, the `SyntheticEvent` isn't passed as the first argument. It's not included at all. Only the parameters you specified will be available.

Answer (score 4):

[Here's my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/deslee/arjjof9a/). I used a list instead of an array to save time, but hopefully you should help you to able to solve your problem. Let me know if you have any questions.

In your example, you have your parameters orders wrong. Your function signature should be `function(index, row, event)`;

Refer to the MDN reference for [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

I would also recommend using the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to debug your parameters in your browser's developer console the next time you are unsure about the order of your parameters.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use `{event => this.handleChange(index, event)}` instead of `{this.handleChange.bind(this, idx)}`.